# How to subtract a constant from members of a sublist?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I know I can subtract a constant from all members of a simple list like this:

```
l = [ 123, 124, 125, 126 ]
l = [v - 100 for v in l]
```

But how can I subtract a constant from one or more specific members of each sublist within a list?

Suppose I have:

```
l = [ [101, 102, 103], [111, 122, 133], [222, 333, 444] ]
```

I want to subtract, say, 100 from the 2nd and 3rd elements of each sublist, to give me:

```
[ [101, 2, 3], [111, 22, 33], [222, 233, 344] ]
```

Is there a straightforward Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simplest form, you can unpack the sublists and apply the operation to the desired items:

```
In [1]: l = [ [101, 2, 3], [111, 22, 33], [222, 233, 344] ]

In [2]: [[x, y - 100, z - 100] for x, y, z in l]
Out[2]: [[101, -98, -97], [111, -78, -67], [222, 133, 244]]
```

Or, a bit more scalable approach would be to have a nested list comprehension:

```
In [3]: [[item[0]] + [x - 100 for x in item[1:]] for item in l]
Out[3]: [[101, -98, -97], [111, -78, -67], [222, 133, 244]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a one-liner, try:

```
l = map(lambda x : x[0:1]+map(lambda y: y-100, x[1:3])+x[3:], l)
```

Python has some nice syntax for very simple things, but for something like this you're best off using functionals or loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x:map(lambda y: y if x.index(y)==0 else y-100,x),l)
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation. It would help both the OP and others with similar problems.